# Movie about flying shark type of creatures

Tags: story-identification, movie

So I am trying to figure out an old movie that I watched as a kid (roughly 8-10 years ago).

Parts of the movie I can remember is that there were these shark-like (or eel-like) creatures that flew around and only some people can see them. I think they were called "Snarks" (not 100% sure).

Comment: Not much to go on here, and I see there's a Close vote for Too Broad. The only thing it puts me in mind of is [The Langoliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Langoliers_(TV_miniseries)).

Comment: "shark" like and "eel" like are pretty different, any more specific?

Comment: sorry for being to broad. It's ok if you guys can't get the answer. I have watched The Langoliers long ago, but it isn't it. (but the film did seem like something out of a stephen king novel). Thanks for mentioning this film got to re-watch this. I'll try watching From Beyond to see what it is. The thing is I was in elementary school when I watched this film on tv. When I try picturing the monsters in the film the only thing that comes to mind is something that looks like the monsters from "From Beyond". Sorry I can't remember the plot, it's just that it was so long ago and I have tried going

Answer (score 4):

It could be *the Langoliers* by Stephen King.

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Langoliers):

> Two creatures, followed by hundreds more, resembling giant meatball-like monsters expanding and contracting with semicircular caves as mouths and chainsaw-like teeth leaving trails of black"

It was turned into [a TV miniseries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Langoliers_%28TV_miniseries%29).

Answer (score 4):

If they look like eels, you *might* be thinking of *From Beyond*:

[image]

Which were only visible after one's pineal gland had been ... adjusted.  Based on an HP Lovecraft story.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091083/